# Get full path as parameter in PowerShell (including space)

Tags: powershell

I'm starting in a powershell script (extract_data.ps1).

He is called with two arguments (path for xml file and path for xsl file)

extract_data.ps1 "C:/Temp/YBA_B Running hyp 2\data.xml" "C:/Temp/YBA_B Running hyp 2\data.xsl"

I've set the script as below

```
#Parameters
Param(
    #[Parameter(Mandatory=$True)]
    [string]$xml,

    #[Parameter(Mandatory=$True)]
    [string]$xsl
)

Write-Host xmlfilelocation: $xml
Write-Host xslfilelocation: $xsl
```

All is OK but if the path contains blank or space, the path is truncated

example :
Path C:/Temp/YBA_B Running hyp 2/data.xml and C:/Temp/YBA_B Running hyp 2/data.xsl
I've got :

xmlfilelocation: C:/Temp/YBA_B
xslfilelocation: Running

instead of

xmlfilelocation: C:/Temp/YBA_B Running hyp 2/data.xml
xslfilelocation: C:/Temp/YBA_B Running hyp 2/data.xsl

Do you have a trick to help me ?

Thank a lot

Comment: Put single quotes around the path.

Comment: @ jdweng : Same result

Comment: Can't reproduce. The call `.\extract_data.ps1 "C:/Temp/YBA_B Running hyp 2\data.xml" "C:/Temp/YBA_B Running hyp 2\data.xsl"` outputs the full paths. You are propably already passing the wrong arguments. For further assistance, please include a [mcve].

Comment: Windows the slashes should be backslashes.

Comment: Hello,
you're right @zett42. 
call .\extract_data.ps1 is working
I made the mistake to call powershell extract_data.ps1 than cause the issue
Thanks a lor for your help